# Hydrodynamic average (with delta function) - lack of understanding

Tags: average, dirac-delta

Consider $\Omega_N=\left\{0\leq x_1\leq x_2\leq\ldots\leq x_N\leq L\right\}$, where $x_i, 1\leq i\leq N$ are, for example, some objects on $[0,L]$.

> > For phenomena occuring on a length scale large compared to the average distance between the objects, it is convenient to go over to a hydrodynamic description, averaging the microscopic quantities over an interval $\Delta R$ which is small on the macroscopic length, but still contains many objects. Therefore, we introduce the local density of the objects
> >     $$
> > m(x,t)=\frac{1}{\Delta R}\int_{\Delta R}dx\sum_{_i}\delta[x-x_i(t)]~~(1)
> > $$

I do not understand (1). What is done there? in which way is this an average?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are taking an interval of length $\Delta R$ and counting the objects within the interval.  You started with all the $x_i$ as coordinates of the objects.  The integral results in the number of objects because for objects outside the interval the delta function is $0$, for objects within the interval the delta function integrates to $1$.  Then dividing by $\Delta R$ gives the density of objects at $x$

Comment: By the way, what is meant by the notation $\langle m(x,t)\rangle$?  Some kind of average? "For hydrodynamic states the ensemble average of the hydrodynamic density $m(x,t)$ agrees with the ensemble average of the microscopic densitiy." Do not understand that.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\,{#1}\,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,\mathrm{Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
$$
\begin{array}{c}
{x\color{#f00}{\mid}\phantom{\Huge AAAAAAAAAA}\color{#f00}{\mid} x + \Delta R}
\\
{\LARGE\bullet\quad\bullet\qquad\color{#f00}{\bullet}\quad\quad\color{#f00}{\bullet}\ \color{#f00}{\bullet}\ \color{#f00}{\bullet}\quad
\color{#f00}{\bullet}\quad\qquad\qquad\color{#f00}{\bullet}\quad\bullet\quad\bullet\quad\bullet\quad\bullet}
\end{array}
$$
In the interval $\ds{\Delta R}$ you are replacing the detailed description by an 'average' over the interval $\ds{\pars{x,x + \Delta R}}$ which is called a 'coarse-graining'. It just 'counts' positions in that interval. Namely, the $\color{#f00}{red}$ points $\ds{\color{#f00}{\LARGE\bullet}}$:
\begin{align}
\mrm{m}\pars{x,t} & \equiv
\left.{1 \over \Delta R}\sum_{i}1
\,\right\vert_{\ \mrm{x}_{\,i}\,\pars{t}\ \in\ \pars{x\,,\,x + \Delta R}}
\label{1}\tag{1}
\end{align}
Hydrodynamic is a *macroscopic* discipline which is valid at length scales larger that the microscopical typical lengths.

---

However,
\begin{align}
\int_{x}^{x + \Delta R}\delta\pars{x - \mrm{x}_{i}\pars{t}}\,\dd x & =
\left\{\begin{array}{rcl}
\ds{1} & \mbox{if} & \ds{\mrm{x}_{i}\pars{t} \in \pars{x,x + \Delta R}}
\\[1mm]
\ds{0}&& \mbox{otherwise}
\end{array}\right.
\\[1cm]
\mbox{and}\quad  
\sum_{i}\int_{x}^{x + \Delta R}\delta\pars{x - \mrm{x}_{i}\pars{t}}\,\dd x &
\,\,\,\, =\,\,\,\,
\pars{\begin{array}{l}
\mbox{Number of particles}
\\
\mbox{'inside'}\ds{\ \pars{x,x + \Delta R}}
\end{array}}
\\ &\,\,\,\, =\,\,\,\,
\left.\sum_{i}1
\,\right\vert_{\ \mrm{x}_{\,i}\,\pars{t}\ \in\ \pars{x\,,\,x + \Delta R}}
\end{align}

---

Replacing this expression in \eqref{1}:
\begin{align}
\mrm{m}\pars{x,t} & \equiv
{1 \over \Delta R}\sum_{i}\int_{x}^{x + \Delta R}\delta\pars{x - \mrm{x}_{i}\pars{t}}\,\dd x =
{1 \over \Delta R}\int_{x}^{x + \Delta R}
\sum_{i}\delta\pars{x - \mrm{x}_{i}\pars{t}}\,\dd x
\end{align}
From this expression, we can see that
$$
\begin{array}{|l|}\hline\mbox{}\\
\ds{\quad\mrm{m}\pars{x,t}}\
\mbox{is the}\ Number\ of\ Particles\ per\ Unit\ Length\,,\
\mbox{in the interval}\ \ds{\pars{x,x + \Delta R}}\,,\quad
\\
\ds{\quad}\mbox{at time}\ \ds{t}.
\\ \mbox{}\\ \hline
\end{array}
$$

> Indeed,
>   $\ds{\rho\pars{x,t} \equiv
> \sum_{i}\delta\pars{x - \mrm{x}_{i}\pars{t}}}$ is the *Linear Density of Particles* or/and the *Number of Particles per unit length* because:
>   $$
> \left\{\begin{array}{l}
> \ds{\rho\pars{x,t} = 0
> \quad\mbox{if}\quad\mrm{x}_{i}\pars{t} \not= x\,,\ \forall\ i}
> \\[3mm] 
> \mbox{and}\ds{\quad\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\rho\pars{x,t}\,\dd x =}\quad
> \mbox{Total Number of Particles.} 
> \end{array}\right.
> $$

Comment: Thanks! And what is meant by $\langle m(x,t)\rangle$? "For hydrodynamic states the ensemble average of the hydrodynamic density m(x,t) agrees with the ensemble average of the microscopic densitiy."

Comment: By the way: what is meant by "unit length" here?

Comment: @mathfemi Lets build an example: Imagine you have $10$ particles in an interval of length equals $2$ inches. Then you have $10/2 = 5$ particles per inch. The $\texttt{unit lenght}$ is $1\ \texttt{inch}$.